# Merging branch that adds new Git LFS type

Tags: git, git-branch, git-lfs

I have an existing Git repository that I've already enabled Git LFS on. I already have this repository using LFS for `*.foo` files, and this is evident in the `.gitattributes` file.

I have a branch `add-bar` on which I decide I want to use Git LFS for `*.bar` files as well. (I haven't added any `*.bar` files to repository yet; my question is not about migrating existing content.) In my `add-bar` branch I will do this:

```
git lfs track "*.bar"
```

I believe this will update my `.gitattributes` file again. Then I will add my `.bar` file.

```
git add example.bar
git commit -m "Added my first bar."
git push -u origin add-bar
```

I'm unsure of exactly how merging back into `master` will work.

```
git checkout master
git merge add-bar
git push
```

The `add-bar` branch has its `.gitattributes` updated to reflect LFS handling `*.bar` files, but the `.gitattributes` in `master` does not. Will the merge happen correctly? Will LFS correctly be used for `*.bar` files, even though `.gitattributes` in `master` doesn't know about them before the merge? Will `git push` happen correctly even though the `*.bar` files were merged before they were recognized as controlled by LFS?

I'm probably not even asking exactly the right questions, or not asking them in the right way. This will probably become obvious the more I work with Git LFS—maybe I just need to review its mechanism again. But hopefully this question and the answers will be helpful to others as well.

To summarize, I'm just unsure of how merging works with Git LFS if the different branches have different `.gitattributes` settings, and at what point LFS takes over.

Answer (score 2):

To check if `git-lfs` is tracking your files after the merge operation, run the below command :

```
git lfs track
```

It should return this

```
Listing tracked patterns
    *.foo (.gitattributes)
    *.bar (.gitattributes)
Listing excluded patterns
```

When you first setup `git-lfs` for your existing repository, you would have committed the `.gitattributes` file. When you perform a merge operation, if there is no conflict then the new `.gitattributes` file should contain the patterns to be tracked from both the branches.

---

> But that wasn't the question. The question was what happens when I
>   start tracking a file type in a branch, updating the branch
>   `.gitattributes`, and adding a file of the new type in the branch; and
>   then merge that branch into master, which isn't yet tracking those
>   files, and which does not yet reflect that new file type in its
>   `.gitattributes`.
>
> For example, at what point does Git LFS take over? If the new file
>   type isn't in `.gitattributes` (that is, in the target branch) at merge
>   time, will the new file type be stored as literal bytes and not a
>   pointer, as `.gitattributes` will be updated only after the new file has
>   been stored?

When you perform the merge operation, Git LFS is not involved. `git` during the merge operation, treats the pointer files and `.gitattributes` as normal files.

If you wish to work with the LFS files in the master branch (after merge operation), you need to perform a checkout operation.

```
git lfs checkout
```

or this to checkout only certain LFS files

```
git lfs checkout path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

More on why `git lfs checkout` is required from the [man-page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-checkout.1.ronn#description) :

> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> Try to ensure that the working copy contains file content for Git LFS
>   objects for the current ref, if the object data is available. Does not
>   download any content, see git-lfs-fetch(1) for that.
>
> Checkout scans the current ref for all LFS objects that would be
>   required, then where a file is either missing in the working copy, or
>   contains placeholder pointer content with the same SHA, the real file
>   content is written, provided we have it in the local store. Modified
>   files are never overwritten.

Comment: But that wasn't the question. The question was what happens when I start tracking a file type in a branch, updating the branch `.gitattributes`, and adding a file of the new type in the branch; and then merge that branch into `master`, which isn't yet tracking those files, and which does not yet reflect that new file type in its `.gitattributes`.

Comment: For example, at what point does Git LFS take over? If the new file type isn't in `.gitattributes` (that is, in the target branch) at merge time, will the new file type be stored as literal bytes and not a pointer, as `.gitattributes` will be updated only _after_ the new file has been stored?

Comment: Thanks for the update. So you're saying that the merge will keep the pointer files in the local repository from the branch even on `master`, and `.gitattributes` will now contain the correct information. Then why do I need to use `git lfs checkout`? The pointer file is in the local repository, but the actual file would be in my working directory, wouldn't it? What will happen if I don't use `git lfs checkout` afterwards?

Comment: @GarretWilson, Before the merge operation, the file types `*.bar` on branch 'add-bar` would be a LFS file in non-pointer format. However, after merge operation in master branch, it will be added as a pointer file. This is because git treats the LFS file as a pointer file. If you want to work on the `*.bar` file in the master branch after the merge operation, you have to checkout the file to restore the real-content (`lfs checkout`).

Comment: If you  don't use `git lfs checkout`,nothing happens. If you wish to modify the LFS tracked files, you have to checkout if they are it their pointer format. The point is that large files should be managed by Git LFS so you need to checkout or else the purpose of LFS is defeated.

Comment: `The pointer file is in the local repository, but the actual file would be in my working directory, wouldn't it? ` : It was in the working directory when you were in the `add-bar` branch. But once you checkout to master it is no longer present.  But I am guessing that once you do a `lfs checkout`, the `*.bar` file would not be downloaded from the LFS server. Instead it would be fetched from `.git` dir which includes the blob for the particular pointer file.

Comment: "But once you checkout to master it is no longer present." Sure, it works like that with or without LFS. But once I merge in the new branch to master, won't the pointer file be in the local repository, and the new file bytes be in my working directory? Or will it place the pointer file in my working directory because LFS doesn't know about it yet?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm busy and don't have time to chat right now. I was pointing out places where your answer could be clearer. I'm sure you know what you're talking about, but your answer isn't the step-by-step description of the state and explanation of the process I was expecting. Your answer may be correct, but it's not immediately clear to my _why_. When I'll have time I'll figure it out and add my own explanation. But thank you for contributing.

Comment: Sure, I will delete the chat link for now, Here's what I posted there w.r.t your previous comment: 
I meant the real content of the file is no longer present (only pointer file is present representing the real content of the file)
Yes, it will just place the pointer file in the working directory, LFS needs to be triggered manually using the lfs checkout to convert the pointer files to real content files

Comment: My understanding of Git LFS is based on what I have observed when using a dummy client repository with a [lfs-test server](https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server), however I would recommend the following links for better understanding :
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki , 
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/tree/master/docs